# Get only extended class variables

Tags: php, oop

I have a class:

```
class Person {
   public $id;
   public $firstName;
   public $lastName
}
```

and another one that extends it:

```
class Student extends Person {
   public $grade;
}
```

The the problem is that when i use [get_object_vars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) on the extended Students class, i also receive the `$id`, `$firstName` and `$lastName` from Person.
How can i get **ONLY** the `$grade` from Student?

I tried to make the variables in person as "protected", but then i am unable to get them with [get_object_vars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: @gvlasov we have our DB class that builds CRUD queries, the object variables are the columns in the database. Student has more properties in a separate table in the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you would probably need to one additional method and the `Reflection` class to get your desired result.

Here is your `Person` class untouched:

```
class Person {
   public $id;
   public $firstName;
   public $lastName;
}
```

And `Student` class with additional `props()` method:

```
class Student extends Person {
   public $grade, $age;

   function props(){
    $class = new ReflectionClass($this);
    $class = $class->getParentClass();
    $props =  $class->getProperties();

    $original = array_map(function($e){
        return $e->name;
    }, $props);

    $original = array_flip($original);

    return array_diff(array_keys(get_class_vars(__CLASS__)), array_keys($original));
   }
}
```

Now the `props()` method will contain the properties declared only in the child class.

```
var_export( (new Student)->props() ); // array (0 => 'grade', 1 => 'age',)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use modified [ReflectionClass::getProperties](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getproperties.php).

```
$studentReflectionClass = new ReflectionClass('Student');
$studentProperties = array_filter(
    $studentReflectionClass->getProperties(),
    function ($properties) use ($studentReflectionClass) {
        return $properties->getDeclaringClass()->getName() === $studentReflectionClass->getName();
    }
);

dump($studentProperties);
```

Output:

```
array:1 [                    
    0 => ReflectionProperty {#4
        +name: "grade"
        +class: "Student"
        modifiers: "public"
    }
]
```